# Word2011 doesn't support "FormattingShowClear", causing a problem on restricted style templates

Tags: macos, vba, office-2010

I have created a Word Template I would like to use in a mixed Office 2010/2011 environment. I am restricting formatting to using recommended styles, which removes the ability to select font, font size, etc.... However I want to allow the template user to still "Clear Formatting".

In Word 2010 (Windows) this works great, the document property `FormattingShowClear` is set to `True`. Unfortunately in Word 2011 (Mac), this property does not exist, so the button and function are disabled. Also, paradoxically in Word 2011 the Bold and Italicize font style buttons are enabled!

I have verified that `FormattingShowClear` is in the list of removed (or never implemented) properties not supported in Office for Mac 2011 (check this list out [here](http://mac2.microsoft.com/vb/1033/Word/html/womscChangesBetweenWord2010and2011.htm) if you like).

Is my only recourse to write my own function using `Word.Selection.ClearFormatting` and assign it to a custom button? Is there a different property in Word for Mac 2011 equivalent to `FormattingShowClear` that I can set to `True` to enable the existing button?

Update
I went ahead and duplicated the Clear Formatting function, but removing the functionality of Bold and Italics on the Home tab of the Ribbon is still frustrating me. I've tried replicating those functions in Macros (shown below) and commenting the functions out. This blocks hotkey and using the formatting toolbar but not the Bold and Italicize buttons on the Home tab of the ribbon.

```
Sub Bold()
    'Selection.Font.Bold =WdToggle
    'Selection.Range.Bold = wdToggle
End Sub
Sub Italic()
' Bold Italics    
    'Selection.Font.Italic=WdToggle
    'Selection.Range.Italic =WdTogg
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> does still work to clear formatting. But it's unconscionable that MS have removed the function behind the menus, while leaving the function label `Clear Formatting` there.